# Stable Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

If X and Y are identical independent Random Variables.I have shown that X+Y and X have same distribution but i am enable to get idea how to proceed to prove X=0 almost surely if X+Y and X have same distribution.Can someone give me hint to prove this?

Comment: You should transform your "Variables. I have shown" by "Variables such". Otherwise it doesn't make sense !

Answer (score 1):

Let the distribution of $X$ ands $Y$ be $p$ (you have said they are i.i.d.  Then
$$
Pr(X+Y=k) = \sum_m Pr(X=m) Pr(Y=k-m) = (p*p)(k)
$$
Here '*' denotes convolution. 
So the distribution of a sum is the convolution of the distributions of the summands.

You have stated that $X+Y$ distributed as $X$. Therefore 
$$
p*p = p
$$
Think about what distribution can be idempotent with respect to convolution.

Comment: But i am confused how we can show X=0 almost surely.

Comment: If your distribution is discrete, you can't. $Pr(0)=1$ will always work. If you're working over the reals, then $p$ can only be the Dirac delta and your statement is true. You need some knowledge of Fourier analysis to see this fully.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Fourier Analysis.Is there any other way to prove it? Any help will work.